# Display topic as mark on rviz and mobile robot model too

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working on ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

I currently have a topic made of geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance and geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance and so on.
And I want to display this topic on rviz.

So, is it necessary to set its own tf setting newly for display? I don't need any process wrt the topic but just to subscribe and display (as a point mark, eg).

And also I have to display my mobile robot simultaneously. When I launch turtlebot's minimal.launch a rviz showed mobile robot topic. So I investigated minimal.launch files, but I couldn't find the codes wrt the robot model topic. I know I also can resolve this issue by simply launching amcl_demo.launch. But if I can, I'd like to display it on my customized rviz field, not on the amcl's field

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334809/display-topic-as-mark-on-rviz-and-mobile-robot-model-too/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

About the covariance topics there are already some discussions about it, see [#q9295](https://answers.ros.org/question/9295/how-can-i-visualize-covariance-data-using-ros-tools/), this [rviz issue on github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/381) and [this blog](https://geus.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/how-to-represent-a-3d-normal-function-with-ros-rviz/). There seems to be a [rviz_plugin_covariance](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_plugin_covariance) developped for Fuerte but it's not available for kinetic, so you would have to build from source (if possible).

> And also I have to display my mobile robot simultaneously. When I launch turtlebot's minimal.launch a rviz showed mobile robot topic

That's not exactly a topic, the robot model is defined by setting the parameter `robot_description`, in rviz the field `Robot Model` will simply read this parameter. You can find it when going further in the `minimal.launch` that there is the call to `robot.launch.xml` that will also call the launch file `description.launch.xml`. In this last file there are those two lines responsible for the definition of the robot model :

```
  <arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" />
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
```

Just as a note : You also need to use the nodes `robot_state_publisher` and `joint_state_publisher` if you want to use `TF`. They both read the parameter `robot_description` to generate the `TF`.

> I'd like to display it on my customized rviz field, not on the amcl's field

Can you clarify what is rviz field and amcl field ? Are you talking about the launch files ?

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-10-08**:
Thank you for your quick response. The rviz 'filed' is,  I meant just the rviz window. I considered which word to use among [field, window, canvas,..] and I chose [field]. In short, the rviz field is a window when the user runs the rviz with [$ rviz] command.  Sorry about the confusion...

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-10-08**:
Don't be sorry I just wanted to fully understand your issue. `Rviz` is a visualization tool so you can directly say "in rviz" and ros users would understand.